# Phonegap won't open camera

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Ok well I am attempting to just get the photo library open up, then from there I will start to work on uploading it to a server. But currently the camera library will not open up. I have copied the example from the docs. I then added the device in the config.xml along with running the cordova plugin add command.

But when I run the app and click the button nothing happens.I'm new to cordova plugins and not a wizard on javascript. I'm also on v3.3 for iOS.

This is in the config.xml

```
 <feature name="Camera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
</feature>
```

This is the photo.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var pictureSource;   // picture source
        var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            pictureSource=navigator.Camera.PictureSourceType;
            destinationType=navigator.Camera.DestinationType;
        }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {

        var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');


        smallImage.style.display = 'block';

        // Show the captured photo
        // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
        //
        smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
        // Uncomment to view the image file URI
        // console.log(imageURI);

        // Get image handle
        //
        var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

        // Unhide image elements
        //
        largeImage.style.display = 'block';

        // Show the captured photo
        // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
        //
        largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    function getPhoto(source) {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.Camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
                                    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
                                    sourceType: source });
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
</body>
```

Comment: @DiveshSalian There is no error code it compiles and runs the simulator when I click the button to open up the camera library nothing happens.

Comment: Have you added the required plugins from the command line? If you fire up the HTML in Chrome, and debug using console, it will normally tell you what's missing

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI
```

to

```
destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
```

in your getPhoto() function.

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
```

Also check this URL for more answers:

[Phonegap Camera API Cannot read property data url of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834145/phonegap-camera-api-cannot-read-property-data-url-of-undefined)